# Дублирует клавиатуру InlineKeyboardMarkup, как исправить?

Tags: python, telegram

Подскажите, как исправить, чтобы не дублировал клавиатуру, получает он нашел 4 ключевых слова, как запретить, чтобы отправлял только одну клавиатуру, пускай хоть 10 слов найдет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Телеграм, библиотека AIOGRAM.

```html
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='Удалить клавиатуру', callback_data='test'))
item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" Правила", callback_data='pravila')
item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" Помощь", callback_data='pomosh')
markup.add(item1, item2)


@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def inline_menu(message):
    words = ['продам', 'продаю', 'продается', 'продаётся', 'Продам', 'Продаю', 'Продаётся', 'требуется', 'Требуется', 'продаём', 'Продаём', 'Цена', 'цена', 'Москва', 'звоните', 'тел']
    for word in words:
        if word in message.text:
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Здравствуйте, {0.first_name}!\n<b>Нажмите нужную кнопку </b>.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
    parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, в вашем случае достаточно будет дописать выход из цикла при первом нахождении слова.

```
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='Удалить клавиатуру', callback_data='test'))
item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" Правила", callback_data='pravila')
item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(" Помощь", callback_data='pomosh')
markup.add(item1, item2)


@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def inline_menu(message):
    words = ['продам', 'продаю', 'продается', 'продаётся', 'Продам', 'Продаю', 'Продаётся', 'требуется', 'Требуется', 'продаём', 'Продаём', 'Цена', 'цена', 'Москва', 'звоните', 'тел']
    for word in words:
        if word in message.text:
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Здравствуйте, {0.first_name}!\n<b>Нажмите нужную кнопку </b>.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
            break
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас, теперь всё работает, как надо.